# SQL Query for the greatest amount of total dollars spent...?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, data-warehouse

SQL for identifing the following query?

Which month shows the greatest amount of total dollars spent on travel and entrainment by customers in each region?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the requirement.

By using the Join Condition we can achieve the desired result.

Please go through the query.

> select L.Region,T.Month,SUM(F.Amount) as Amount_Spent  from Fact_Table F
>   Inner join time_table T on F.timekey = T.timekey 
>   Inner join Location_table L on F.LocationKey = L.Locationekey where f.purchasekey = 2
>   Group by T.Month,L.Region

Answer (score 1):

Try using :

```
SELECT TOP 1 d.[Month]
FROM [Fact Table] t
INNER JOIN [Time Dimension] d ON d.[Time Key]=t.[Time Key]
ORDER BY t.[Amount] DESC
```

Comment: @user1460480 Think about putting this to "solution" if this solved you problem

Comment: Can you please tell me how can I put it into solution

Comment: You just did by "accepting" this answer.